# How We fetch data from graphql api in powerBI

Tags: graphql, powerbi, bigdata, data-manipulation

I want to fetch data from GraphQl api in directly to Power Bi how I can That

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the auth for the API is API Key, Basic, Windows, or AAD, you can use the Web connector.  For other Authentication scenarios you may need a [custom connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/startingtodevelopcustomconnectors).

And I would use the Advanced Power Query Editor for this, rather than trying to configure it through the Wizard.

EG

```
let
    uri = "https://countries.trevorblades.com",
    query = "{
  country(code: ""BR"") {
    name
    native
    capital
    emoji
    currency
    languages {
      code
      name
    }
  }
}",
    source = uri & "?query=" & Uri.EscapeDataString(query),
    resp = Web.Contents(source),
    json = Json.Document(resp,65001),
    data = json[data],
    country = data[country],
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(country),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Converted to Table", List.Distinct(#"Converted to Table"[Name]), "Name", "Value")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```